# Is ln(1+e^z) transcendent for all algebraic z?

Tags: number-theory

Is $\ln(1+e^z)$ transcendent for all algebraic $z$?

I already know Schanuel's conjecture and Baker's theorem. But I don't know how they can help here.

Comment: In other words: Are there algebraic numbers $z,w$ with $e^z+1-e^w=0$?

Answer (score 2):

We have Lindemann's theorem:

> For any *distint*  algebraic numbers $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ and any non-zero algebraic numbers $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$, we have
>   $$\beta_1e^{\alpha_1}+\ldots+\beta_ne^{\alpha_n}\ne 0 $$

So assume $z$ and $w:=\ln(1+e^z)$ are algebraic. We have $e^z-e^w+e^0=0$, which the theorem allows only if $1,w,z$ are not distinct, i.e., in the following cases

- $w=z$. But then $e^0=0$, which is absurd
- $w=0$. But then $e^z=0$, which is absurd
- $z=0$. But then $w=\ln 2$, which is transcendental (again by Lindemann from  $2e^0-e^w=0$)